# How to pass parent column value in subquery in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to pass _user_id column value inside with in $query. this is hasMany relationship. I am not able to figure out how to user user_id of RFX into the $query where condition.

```
public function response_pricings(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Website\RFXRequestPricingResponse', ['rfx_request_id'=>'_rfx_request_id', 'user_id'=>'_user_id'])->selectRaw("*");
}

return RFXRequestSupplierResponded::select(
    'id as _id',
    'rfx_request_id as _rfx_request_id',
    'user_id as _user_id',
    'status',
    'is_qualified',
    DB::RAW('(SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=user_id) as user_name'),
    DB::RAW('(SELECT note FROM rfx_request_response_notes WHERE rfx_request_id='.$rfx_request_id.' AND user_id=rfx_request_suppliers_responded.user_id LIMIT 1) as note')
)
->with(
    [
        'response_pricings' => function ($query) {
            /*$query->where('user_id', $_user_id);*/
        }
    ]
)
->where('rfx_request_id',$rfx_request_id)
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have defined a relationship on a model, Laravel would automatically link the models using either the dynamically determined foreign keys or foreign keys that you have specified. Therefore you don't need to pass in the `user_id` to the query. Laravel would automatically use the the `user_id` of the `RFXRequestSupplierResponded` instance.

However, it looks like you are linking the `RFXRequestSupplierResponded` to the `RFXRequestPricingResponse` model using multiple foreign keys. Eloquent doesn't have built-in support for that. Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077890/laravel-eloquent-multiple-foreign-keys-for-relationship) for examples on how to add support for multiple foreign keys.

Answer (score -1):

You pass local scope parameters to closure functions using `use`

```
... ->with(
        ['response_pricings' => function ($query) use ($_user_id) {
            $query->where('user_id', $_user_id);
         }
        ]
      )
      ->where(....
```

More info in this Q&A: [In PHP 5.3.0, what is the function "use" identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier)

Comment: i need to pass column "_user_id" of RFXRequestSupplierResponded