# Laravel 5.6 - 3 level relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**I have the following Models:**

- Assessment
- Upload
- Grade

**These are their relationships:**

- Assessment hasMany Upload
- Upload belongsTo Assessment
- Upload hasOne Grade
- Grade belongsTo Upload

**Tables:**

- users
- assessment (id, user_id, name)
- uploads (id, assessment_id, grade_id, filename, size)
- grade (id, name)

**I'm currently doing this, but want to get/show the grade name too of the upload, but not sure how?:**

```
@foreach ($assessment->uploads as $upload)
  {{ $upload }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your question.

Make relation like i edited .

- Assessment hasMany Upload
- Upload belongsTo Assessment
- Upload belongsTo Grade
- Grade hasMany Upload

And then try this

```
@foreach ($assessment->uploads as $upload)
 {{ $upload->grade->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Assessment hasMany Upload,
Upload belongsTo Assessment,
Upload belongsTo Grade,
Grade hasMany Upload, This is your correct relationship. change to this

Answer (score 1):

Anyone struggling with converting legacy code to Laravel...when you need to join tables on multiple columns, I highly recommend using https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships!

I ran into this excellent code while reading an article here:
[Laravel Eloquent: multiple foreign keys for relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077890/laravel-eloquent-multiple-foreign-keys-for-relationship?rq=1)