# Use two foreign key and two owner key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

In laravel Eloquent: Relationships I want to use two foreign key and two owner key.

How can I do this?

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        User::class,
        'foreign_key1',
        'owner_key1',
        'foreign_key2',
        'owner_key2'
    );
}
```

Comment: Please share what are you trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Providing more context will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The work around is you can create 2 relationship methods to specify each User's relationship, if this is what you really want:

```
public function firstUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'foreign_key1', 'owner_key1');
}

public function secondUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'foreign_key2', 'owner_key2');
}
```

I don't think there is any other way to solve this.

If this answer is not good for you, consider adding more explanation to the question like what linktoahref said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Eloquent supports composite keys, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077890/laravel-eloquent-multiple-foreign-keys-for-relationship).

In that post they mention this package
https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships that provides support for it.